# Ubuntu Duplicate sources.list entry error on sudo apt-get install scala

Tags: scala, ubuntu, sudo, apt-get

I'm trying to install scala and keep running into this error when I type:

```
sudo apt-get install scala
```

I've got the following errors:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/toolbelt.heroku.com_ubuntu_._en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I followed these instructions on how to fix it but it didn't work.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry

Here is my sources.list file

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213)]/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Answer (score 0):

start a terminal and type:

```
gksu gedit
```

then type

```
open /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

and then look for the appropriate entry that's said to be a duplicate.

Check if they are the same and if that's the case enter a `#` in front of the duplicate entry.

Then save the file an in another terminal enter
`sudo apt-get update` to check if the error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked with me.

First remove the duplicate source `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list`
then  `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2316649

Answer (score 0):

Since it is easy to run python in ubuntu. You can use the following python3 script to make a copy of the file with no duplicates. After which you can replace the older "sources.list" with the new file

```
l = set()
# remove duplicates by adding all the lines to a set
with open("/etc/apt/sources.list") as f:
    for line in f:
        l.add(line)
# write the new lines to a file in your home folder
with open("/home/brianbrix/sources.list", "w") as f:
    for line in l:
        f.write(line)
        f.write("\n")

# after that you can replace the sources file wwith the new one which has no duplicates
```

Comment: Don't forget to create a backup of the original  "/etc/apt/sources.list" before replacing it with the new file